# Stop a function at a dynamic point based on its parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dynamic

Hi I'm wondering if I can stop this function at a dynamic point based of its parameters.
This is for a game and the game engine uses its own methods for printing the text.

```
function FillQuestJournal(activeQuests);
Quest0.text = quests[0]
Quest1.text = quests[1]
Quest2.text = quests[2]
Quest3.text = quests[3]
Quest4.text = quests[4]
Quest5.text = quests[5]
Quest6.text = quests[6]
Quest7.text = quests[7]
Quest8.text = quests[8]
Quest9.text = quests[9]
Quest10.text = quests[10]
Quest11.text = quests[11]
Quest12.text = quests[12]
Quest13.text = quests[13]
Quest14.text = quests[14]
Quest15.text = quests[15]
```

The function prints each element of the array on a new line and I want it to stop when it has printed the element at the end of the array so that it doesn't print "undefined" on everyline afterwards.
quests is an array and I want the function to stop at a point based of the parameter: activeQuests, which contains the length of the array. So if activeQuests=6 then the function will stop as soon as it has completed this line:

```
Quest6.text = quests[6]
```

EDIT: Ok so this is the background:

```
width = ui.getWidth();
height = ui.getHeight();
centerX = width/2;
centerY = height/2;
Quest0 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 90);
Quest1 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 80);
Quest2 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 70);
Quest3 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 60);
Quest4 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 50);
Quest5 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 40);
Quest6 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 30);
Quest7 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 20);
Quest8 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY - 10);
Quest9 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY);
Quest10 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY + 10);
Quest11 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY + 20);
Quest12 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY + 30);
Quest13 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY + 40);
Quest14 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY + 50);
Quest15 = UILabel(" ", centerX - 200, centerY + 60);
```

This creates a series of lines of blank text that are then filled with the elements from the array in the function I printed earlier in the post. Keep in mind this is using methods from the program I'm using.

Comment: Is Objects "Quest0","Quest1" is dynamic or static? Have you used jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'for' or 'while'

```
var q;
while(q < activeQuests) {

    //Do whatever 

    q++;
}
```

---

```
for (var q=0; q<activeQuests; q++) {

    //Do whatever

}
```

What exactly you are trying here? If you can provide some background, there may be better ways to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. It may be as you want.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var quests = [];
        // set array variables
        quests[0] = "val0";
        quests[1] = "val1";
        quests[2] = "val2";
        quests[3] = "val3";
        quests[4] = "val4";
        quests[5] = "val5";

        function FillQuestJournal(activeQuests) {
            $("#Quest" + activeQuests).val(quests[activeQuests]);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /// call the fill question function
         // pass parameter 5    
            FillQuestJournal(5)
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="text" value="0" id="Quest0" />
    <input type="text" value="1" id="Quest1" />
    <input type="text" value="2" id="Quest2" />
    <input type="text" value="3" id="Quest3" />
    <input type="text" value="4" id="Quest4" />
    <input type="text" value="5" id="Quest5" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can print values then used as below example..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function FillQuestJournal(activeQuests) {
            $("#data").html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < activeQuests; i++) {
                $("#data").append("Quest" + i + ".text = quests[" + i + "]");
                $("#data").append("<br>");
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /// call the fill question function
         // pass parameter 5    
            FillQuestJournal(5)
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="data">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```